# travelling from philippines to US with lay over in japan

Tags: transit, japan, filipino-citizens

i read that there is no visa needed for a short layover in japan just want to make sure because what i read was posted few year ago. my parents will be having their layover in japan for 3 hours, going to Dallas Texas the same day. thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, the software used by airlines to determine visa requirements for passengers, they will not need a visa as long as their onward flight is on the same CALENDAR day (ie arrive August 12 and leave August 12) and they cannot leave the transit area.